# Does flat group delay bandwidth of a Thiran filter increase with increase in filter order?

Tags: infinite-impulse-response, group-delay, allpass

Experimentally, it does seem that for a Thiran allpass delay filter of desired low-frequency group delay $D$ with filter order $N$, increase in filter order $N$ increases bandwidth of the frequency region that has approximately flat group delay response of group delay $D$. For convenience, let $D=N+1$ such that actual delay, accounting for filter order delay of $N$, is $1$. In such a case, is it true that increase of $N$ increases flat group delay bandwidth? How do I prove it theoretically?

To say it in other ways, does increase of $N$ lead to increase in $k$ such that $|H(\omega) - e^{-i\omega D}| < \epsilon$ for $|\omega| < k$ ?